# How create video file from bitmap array by NReco

Tags: c#, nreco

I have pictures from the camera and I'd like to save them as a video. I do not have pictures saved as files, I just keep them in my memory (like Bitmap).

**The headword method I need might look like this:**

```
public void createVideoFileFromBitmapList(List<Bitmap> inputList, String pathToOutputFile){

}
```

**I tried to use the example:**

> NReco.VideoConverter.Examples.LiveStreamFromImages.csproj

But I do not like the fact that there is a * .h264 file in the process and the resulting video is too compressed.